# I cant stop web page from posting when I click button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked at multiple solutions on stack overflow and non of them have worked.

When I click the button, it take me to a new url   yoursite.com/index.html?message=blah&pass=12

I want it to stay in the same page and just execute the script I wrote.

Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Simple Encryption Using Caesar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/marx-css/css/marx.min.css">

        <style>
            .hidden{
                visibility: hidden;
            }

        </style>
        <script src="encrypt.js"></script> 



    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h2>What is this?</h2>

            <p>This application was built to <b>encrypt</b> data using the <b>Caesar method.</b>
                 All encryption is handled on <i>client side</i> in order to garuntee <b>data integrity.</b> </p>


            <form onsubmit=" event.preventDefault; doStuff(); ">
                <h5>Insert some text in the following box:</h5> <br>
                <textarea id="userText" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your secret message" autofocus></textarea>
                <br>
                <h5>Enter Your Favorite Number</h5> <br>
                <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Enter Your Favorite Number:"> <br>


                <button id="encrypt" type="submit" onclick="return false;" style="width: 100%;">Lets Encrpt</button>

                <div id="emessage"></div>

            </form>



        </main>

        <script>

            window.onload = function(){ doStuff(); };

            function doStuff(){
                document.getElementById("encrypt").onclick = function(){

                    var key = document.getElementById("pass").value;
                    var message = document.getElementById("userText").innerHTML;

                    var eMessage = caesarShift(message,key);

                    document.getElementById("emessage").innerHTML = eMessage ;




                    }
            }




        </script>



    </body>

</html>
```

I have another js file called encrypt.js which has a function called `caesarShift()`

I don't know why this isnt working. Please help!

Comment: might be issue with compiling.

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal how would i debug that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code a bit to make it more simple to do the stuff you are looking for.

You need to define the `caesarShift` function that you are calling. Unless you define that you won't get the answer you are looking for in the div `emessage`.

Also you need to change to `event.PreventDefault()` if you want to use your method only and then define the `caesarShift` and then call it.
HTML Part -->

```
<form>
                <h5>Insert some text in the following box:</h5> <br>
                <textarea id="userText" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your secret message" autofocus></textarea>
                <br>
                <h5>Enter Your Favorite Number</h5> <br>
                <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Enter Your Favorite Number:"> <br>


                <button id="encrypt" type="button" onclick="doStuff()" style="width: 100%;">Lets Encrpt</button>

                <div id="emessage"></div>

            </form>
```

JS part -->

```
<script>
            function doStuff(){
                var key = document.getElementById("pass").value;
                var message = document.getElementById("userText").value;

                // Define this caesarShift function
                var eMessage = caesarShift(message,key);


                document.getElementById("emessage").innerHTML = eMessage ;

            }

            // window.onload = function(){ doStuff(); };


        </script>
```

Comment: worked by just fixing the form.. the caesarShift() is alreay defined encrypt.js

Answer (score 6):

Change `event.preventDefault` to `event.preventDefault()`.

The former only references the function while the latter actually invokes it.

Comment: fixed half my problem.. it no longer goes to the link.

Comment: It still doesnt do the part where its supposed set the text to the caesarShift return variabel